# How do I display content from a Wiki page in another page in redmine?

Tags: ruby, redmine, wiki, display

I'm trying to display content from one wiki page in redmine in my welcome/index file.

I've tried linking pages with `[[foo]]` (which I have found out only works in the wiki itself) and `!{{include(projectname:stuff)}}`, but when I try to use this, my redmine only displays it as plain text.

```
<div class="splitcontentright">
 <div class="news box">
  <h3><%=("News")%></h3>
    !{{include(MyWikiPage:MyArticle))}}
    <%= call_hook(:view_welcome_index_right, :projects => @projects) %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is this the wrong method? Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After skimming trough redmines code I found the solution.

Instead of writing

```
!{{include(MyWikiPage:MyArticle)}}
```

you'll have to write:

```
    <%= textilizable "{{include(Project:Article)}}" %>
```

this calls the textilizable function which let's you use wiki macros from wherever you want.